# How to handle correctly a URL having twice the same parameters with same values?

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Using Grails 1.3.3, when requesting url link:

```
/myapp/mycontroller/myaction?p1=v1&p2=v2&p1=v1
```

then params injected value into Grails controller will contain :

```
assert params.p1== ['v1','v1']
```

It would have been logical to me that `params.p1` equals to '`v1'`, no?

In any case, is there any way to change this behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What is **params.myparam1**? You don't have that in the code, you just have **p1** and **p2**. Are you asking whether **params.p1** should just have a single value result instead of a list of results?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typed mistake : question updated

Answer (score 1):

i agree with @Andrew, but of you must

p1.unique()[0] == 'v1'

Comment: wouldn't that fail if there was only one parameter (p1) since it won't be an array?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a bug in your app that the parameter is twice?  Most people would think that should mean it has multiple values, hence it wouldn't be considered strange behavior.  You can always grab the query string and parse it yourself if you don't like the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want it to pick up the duplicates because you don't want to have to write code in every controller action to handle that special case. The only thing I can tell you is to not allow the duplicates in the first place, or intercept the request using [a filter](http://www.grails.org/Filters) and substitute the duplicate param values.